# transparent background image but not transparent div containers

Tags: css, html

I'm somewhat new to html but im tyring to have a transparent background image and in the body have div containers that show the background image just not transparently.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say, "do the opposite", but I really need more information (or an example).
If you used one background image and set specific classes up for the divs that can see the image, would you be able to get the effect you want?

CSS example:

```
html body { background-image: url("myimage.jpg"); }
div { background: #FFFFFF; }
.peek { background: transparent; }
```

HTML example:

```
<body>
<div> section with white background (blocks the background image), contains text </div>
<div class="peek"> section that exposes the background image, reveals different aspects of the background when the page is scrolled </div>
```

Please let me know if I understood what your goal was.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you're looking for something like this:

```
<style>
    * {
        color: white;
    }

    .background {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        position: relative;

        background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/730896/pexels-photo-730896.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260');
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

        .side {
            width: 20%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;

            background-color: red;
        }

        .main {
            width: 60%;
            height: 100%;

            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;

            background-color: transparent;
        }

            .top, .spacer, .bottom {
                width: 100%;
                height: 20%;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;

                background-color: red;
            }

            .content {
                width: 100%;
                height: 20%;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
            }

            .section-one {
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            }
            .section-two {
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
            }
</style>

<div class="background">

    <div class="side">THIS IS WHITE</div>

    <div class="main">

        <div class="top">THIS IS WHITE</div>

        <div class="content section-one">THIS HAS A BG IMAGE THAT IS SET TO THE CONTAINER DIV</div>

        <div class="spacer">THIS IS WHITE</div>

        <div class="content section-two">THIS HAS A BG IMAGE THAT IS SET TO THE CONTAINER DIV</div>

        <div class="bottom">THIS IS WHITE</div>

    </div>

    <div class="side">THIS IS WHITE</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I would also highly recommend **not** using this method. I can't imagine it will be easy to maintain / make flexible.